# Reading two lines and writing in one line

Tags: python, concatenation

I am new to python. Using below mentioned code to get two lines as one in a another txt file

```
import glob

dirname = 'F:\\mmml'

list_of_files = glob.glob(dirname+'/*.mml')

with open("F:\\d.txt", "w") as fout:

        for fileName in list_of_files:
            for line in open(fileName, "r"):
                if line.startswith('MOD:') or line.startswith('EQUIPMENT:'):
                   fout.writelines(line)
```

But I am getting result in vertical order like

```
MOD

EQUIPMENT
```

But I want output be

```
MOD EQUIPMENT
```

I could not understand existing solutions for similar problems.

Comment: Can you add a sample of your text file?

Comment: MOD xxxx=70006, yyyyyyyy, zzzzzzzzz

Comment: EQUIPMENT:DID=, BATIMS=OFF, PAE=OFF;

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that when you do `for line in open(fileName, "r"):` the newline (`\r\n`/`\n`) at the end of `line` is still present. So you just have to `strip()` the `line` to solve your problem:

```
for line in open(fileName, "r"):
    if line.startswith('MOD:') or line.startswith('EQUIPMENT:'):
       fout.writelines(line.strip())
```

or use the `splitlines` method:

```
for line in open(fileName, "r").read().splitlines():
    if line.startswith('MOD:') or line.startswith('EQUIPMENT:'):
       fout.writelines(line)
```

Note that you could do the last for loop in one line:

```
fout.writelines(' '.join(line.strip() for line in open(fileName, "r") \
    if line.startswith('MOD:') or line.startswith('EQUIPMENT:')))
```